# Should Relay GraphQL be organized hierarchically from user down?

Tags: graphql, relay

Should GraphQL server serving Relay have the data organized always from user down? Or is it better to have separate root queries for User (and profile), Friends, Matches?

```
User (viewer)
|
+ Profile
|
+ Friends
|  + Friend 1
|  + Friend 2
|
+ Matches
   + Match 1
     + Date
     + Location
     + Oponent
```

Comment: I believe this is simply a matter of preference as to how many entry points you wish to have on your GraphQL server and how each node relates. Greater exposure always runs the risk for potential security holes so always watch out for that. I'd imagine that with deeply nested trees you take a hit on performance. So if your user is authenticated, rather than querying through a User node, why not pass a token to Matches and let the directly bypass multiple branches of the graph?

Comment: My server implementation depends on this. I'm doing it in Python/Django and the way I choose to expose the tree depends how I need to structure my ORM code. I will start with user, but will see on case by case basis if some models could have their own direct root queries. At least that's the idea for now.

Comment: I had done something similar, using my User as an authentication point of reference. I know some Flask libraries require this. However I ultimately ended up creating a custom JWT solution and had each entry points require a JWT token argument. It would be something worth benchmarking if your software scales out and you notice any noticeable performance hit. But then again, I find GraphQL to be very performant.